# Apple HealthKit data via REST API (update 2018)

Tags: api, apple-watch, healthkit

Is it possible to get data from Apple Watch the same way as you would query regular API (With user's consent) to store in my webapp?

Something like: healthkit.com/api/v1/user/GetStepsCount/today

If yes, where can I find a list of available methods? If not, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no web API for HealthKit data.

Answer (score 0):

HealthKit data are only saved in local device and can only query from HKQuery